# How to force an error in a gnumake file

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I want to detect a condition in my makefile where a tool is the wrong version and force the make to fail with an error message indicating the item is not the right version.

Can anyone give an example of doing this?

I tried the following but it is not the right syntax:

```
ifeq "$(shell svnversion --version | sed s/[^0-9\.]*://)" "1.4"
$error("Bad svnversion v1.4, please install v1.6")
endif
```

Thanks.

Comment: You might want to check this against 1.4. I have 1.4.4 installed and the `--version` output contains a lot more than the version number. Try something like `ifeq "$(shell svn --version | sed -nE -e '/version/s/^.*([0-9]+\.[0-9]\+)\..*$$/\1/p')" "1.4"` instead

Comment: My sed does not accept the -E:

"sed: invalid option -- E"

Comment: Does it have to be make?  I tend to write these tests in configure.

Comment: Ah.. then change the _match_ portion of the expression to `^.*\([0-9][0-9]*\.[0-9][0-9]*\)\..*$$`. The `-E` would enable _extended regular expressions_ which allow for more compact expressions amongst other goodies.

Comment: I'd recommend quoting the regular expression for the shell too. Just to be safe. I.e., `ifeq ($(shell svnversion --version | sed '<regexp>'))` Saves you the trouble of worrying about which special characters the shell is going to gobble up and misinterpret (except for single-quotes themselves: replace single-quotes in the quoted-string with `'\''` (`single-quote back-slash single-quote single-quote`) to escape them.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

From the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/make/Make-Control-Functions.html):

```
$(error Bad svn version v1.4, please install v1.6)
```

This will result `make` to a fatal error:

```
$ make
Makefile:2: *** Bad svn version v1.4, please install v1.6.  Stop.
```

Comment: As a side note, I wanted to output a multiline error message. For that, you can `define err_mesg = your multiline error mesage ... endef`, and then, `$(error $(err_mesg))`. Make will keep and output `err_mesg` as it was written.

Comment: Minor pitfall: if outside of a recipe, there cannot be whitespace before the `$`

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when used with a shell conditional.

Answer (score 14):

While $(error... works, sometimes its easier to use a rule that fails

```
test_svn_version:
        @if [ $$(svn --version --quiet | \
                perl -ne '@a=split(/\./); \
                          print $$a[0]*10000 + $$a[1]*100 + $$a[2]') \
              -lt 10600 ]; \
        then \
            echo >&2 "Svn version $$(svn --version --quiet) too old; upgrade to v1.6";
            false; \
        fi
```

Then you make test_svn_version a prerequisite of your top level target.

Comment: This isn't working, I get:

/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file

Comment: @WilliamKF -- There's a spurious space after a \ at the end of a line that causes that problem.  I also fixed the missing |

Comment: The rule to choose between `$(error)` (parse-time check) and `false` AKA `exit 1` (run-time target) is: use `$(error)` if your build cannot proceed at all; otherwise, if only specific targets cannot be built without this precondition, make them depend on `test_svn_version`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer! You helped my quite a lot for a related question: how to implement a 'checking target' 

Answer (score 8):

The conditional needs some attention too.

```
ifeq ($(shell svnversion --version | sed s/[^0-9\.]*://), 1.4) 
    $(error Bad svnversion v1.4, please install v1.6)
endif
```

Comment: To use this I could not have $(error ...) tabbed in.

Comment: No tabs, one must use spaces