# How to force an error in BSD make

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make, bsdmake

Is there a way to force an error in a BSD makefile without using a target?  I'm looking for something like

```
.if ...some condition...
    error bad configuration
.endif
```

This question is like "[How to force an error in a gnumake file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1864385/how-to-force-an-error-in-a-gnumake-file)", but is for BSD makefiles.

Answer (score 4):

Yes: use `.error` (and the variable assignment syntax `VARIABLE != some command` to assign the output of a shell command to a variable).

```
SOMEVAR != foo --bar
.if (${SOMEVAR} != "some string")
.error bad configuration
.endif
```

(The man page, which can be read online [here](http://netbsd.gw.com/cgi-bin/man-cgi?make++NetBSD-current) if you don't have it to hand, has full details of the syntax.)

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know of a solution that works for ancient versions of bsd make that don't support the .error directive?  I'm using a Solaris version that silently ignores the directive.

Comment: No, I don't - sorry.  (I do know that there's a version of BSD make called [bmake](http://www.crufty.net/help/sjg/bmake.html) which claims to be quite portable, if that helps?)

Comment: I can confirm that `bmake` used to be very compatible with make on FreeBSD (now they are the same, so it is easier) and I used it on Solaris with my `bsdowl` make macros. — https://bitbucket.org/michipili/bsdowl